# What ate my cabbage?

Tags: cabbage

I'd like to know what might have eaten my cabbage and what can I do to prevent it in the future?

This is how it looks after it's been devoured:
[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell only looking at bite marks. It could be more than only one suspect, think of snails/slugs, caterpillars, or beetles. Try to check if you can see any animals still on the plants to know what is eating it.

Comment: @benn Unfortunately I didn't see any culprits. But I can tell you I have't encountered any snails or caterpillars around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cabbage loopers , green caterpillars , the adults are white butterflys. BT ( bacillus thurengensis) is the main control today. Some time ago I used malathion spray or sevin dust ,but they are politically incorrect today.

Comment: I agree BT (bacillus thurengensis) is a good control. Brassicas are very susceptible to caterpillars and worms. Neem oil with a couple drops of Dawn dish soap in a spray bottle has been effective for me in controlling infestations when I don't have any bacillus thurengensis.